# 80s/90s YA horror book about an all-girls school taking a trip to an amusement park and being stalked by a killer

Tags: story-identification, horror

I can’t remember title or author but the plot is about an all girls school trip with the nuns to a theme park. The protagonist and her friend go on a ride and it stops halfway round. The girls then get stalked by a killer (I think she was female), and the protagonist either gets away or kills the villain.

Comment: Welcome Fiona. Can you tell us about any Sci-Fi or Fantasy elements in the book (as per our remit here)? Please take our [tour] and refer to our [help] for our guidelines.

Comment: If it turns out this is not Fantasy or Sci-Fi, the Literature SE is a good place to ask.